# Advance from currrent cursor position to next line not containing one of several expressions

Tags: search

In vim, is there a way to advance from the current line or cursor position to the next line that doesn't contain one of several regular expressions?  For example, I can use `/RegExp/<CR>` or `:g/RegExp/<CR>`, but I want to go to the next line that *doesn't* match `RegExp`, which could be quite a bit further down.  `RegExp` might be `^  inflating: \|^ extracting:` .  Command `g!/RegExp/<CR>` does not do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I found that `/^\(  inflating: \| extracting: \)\@!<CR>` works.

For years if not decades, I found that zero-width matches evaded intuitive comprehension, especially those of the backward and non-matching type.  For this reason, I've posted this answer rather than erasing the question.  If this is too elementary, just let me know in the comments and I will erase the question.  Thanks.

Comment: No, this is great to have. I think there might be a dupe, but I can't really be bothered to go find it… so have some rep :)